# Bind external HTML component file to json data from calling page in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, binding

with Angular 14, I'm using an ag grid to display rows of data in my main component page. I select a row, click a button and I want to call an auxiliary component HTML file in a separate directory that contains its own typescript file. I am able to collect the row data as JSON data but I want to insert the auxiliary component HTML into my main page.

Q: How can I bind the auxiliary html component to appear in my main html?

*Directory Structure*

```
ClientApp
   src
     app
        MyObject
            MyObject-grid-main
                 MyObject-grid-main.css
                 MyObject-grid-main.html
                 MyObject-grid-main.ts
            MyObject-grid-auxiliary
                 MyObject-grid-auxiliary.css
                 MyObject-grid-auxiliary.html
                 MyObject-grid-auxiliary.ts
```

---

**MyObject-grid-main.html**

```
<button (click)="getSelectedRowData()">Get More Info</button>
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid id="ag-grid"></ag-grid/angular>
...
<div>
<!-- Here I want to insert MyObject-grid-auxiliary.html after I bind the JSON data -->
</div>
```

---

**MyObject-grid-main.ts**

```
@ViewChild('agGrid' grid!: GridApi;
getSelectedRowData()
{
    const selectedData = this.grid.getSelectedRows();
    const jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(selectedData);
    alert(`Selected Data:\n${jsonDataString}`); // display in popup

   // Here is where I want to bind the JSON data to the MyObject-grid-auxiliary.html
   // and have it appear in the place holder above

}
```

---

**MyObject-grid-auxiliary.html**

```
<h2 class="title">{{data.title}}</h2>
...
<span>{{data.remarks}}</span>
...
<tr *ngFor="let pos of data.locations">
                <td>
                  <span>{{pos.position.lat}}</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span>{{pos.position.long}}</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span>{{pos.lastReportedOnDateTime}}</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply pass a `MyObject-grid-main.ts` class property set at first to null as `MyObject-grid-auxiliary` input and then check in the auxiliary component with an ngIf when the data are set, then show your stuff.

in `getSelectedRowData` set the class property and content should will be display in the auxiliar component

Update with example:

in your `MyObject-grid-main.ts` add a new property called

```
auxiliarData = null;
```

in `MyObject-grid-main.html` add the auxiliary component where you need.

```
<myobject-grid-auxiliary [data]="auxiliarData"></myobject-grid-auxiliary>
```

in the function `getSelectedRowData` add the update logic, example

```
const selectedData = this.grid.getSelectedRows();
const jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(selectedData);
alert(`Selected Data:\n${jsonDataString}`);
...
this.auxiliarData = selectedData;
```

in `MyObjectGridAuxiliary.ts`

```
export class MyObjectGridAuxiliary {
    @Input() data = '';
}
```

in `MyObject-grid-auxiliary.html`

```
<div *ngIf="data"> put your html here ... </div>
```

so, whenever the MyObjectGridAuxiliary.data is defined the component will show you html with your data.

Comment: I need to remain on the main page. will your suggestion allow for that? could you provide a code snippet for it? I'm not super well versed in angular yet :\

Comment: i added an example